# How to enter numbers in blackberry without pressing alt key

Tags: blackberry

In my application the user needs to enter numbers.  On the phone one always needs to press the alt key for numbers. How can I programmatically allow the user to enter numbers in the edit field without pressing the alt key?  Please give an example.

Comment: Just a quick comment - I noticed that most of your BlackBerry questions end with "using eclipse" and it's usually not relevant to the question.  So you could probably just remove it from the title, unless the problem really lies with the IDE itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
BasicEditField bef = new BasicEditField(BasicEditField.FILTER_NUMERIC);
```

and if you want to set filter on the fly.

```
bef.setFilter(TextFilter.get(TextFilter.NUMERIC));
```